# Asp.net MVC Is it safe to keep sensitive info in Session?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a basic Authentication system on my Asp.net MVC Website

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: false)

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

I also have a `UserInfoViewModel` class where i keep some user specific information, and i use it on different pages.

To avoid creating the `UserInfoViewModel` every time i need it, i want to save it in Session on Login method.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: false)
   var userInfoViewModel = new UserInfoViewModel();
   Session["userInfo"] = userInfoViewModel;

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Considering that i have sensitive information that i rely on inside `UserInfoViewModel`, like `IsSuperuser`, is it safe to keep that object in Session? Will it expire when the user login session expires as well?

**SOLUTION**

`System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` is exacly made for that. It saves inside AUTH cookie custom user information you need, so you don't recalculate it every time.

[Use Custom Principal Objects video turorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/use-custom-principal-objects)

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safe because the Session is stored on the server. But you have another problem you should be thinking about if you decide to use ASP.NET Sessions. If this session is stored in the memory of the web server (default), IIS could recycle your application at any time and you will loose this session data. On the other hand the user will still be authenticated because he is tracked by a forms authentication cookie which will still be sent. So if you want to use Sessions I would recommend you switching to an out-of-proc session provider (such as `StateServer` or `SQLServer`).

Also as @Mikeb is pointing out in the comments section there's another very serious issue with the Session. If you enabled it for read and write mode for a given controller you will not be able to process multiple requests from the same session in parallel. The server will block and process them sequentially. Think for example multiple AJAX requests from the same session. They will all block and process sequentially.

Comment: What about "Will it expire when the user login session expires as well"?

Comment: This will depend on what timeout you have defined for the session and where is this session stored. But in general if you are using the default settings the session is stored InProc meaning that if IIS recycles your application all session information will be lost while the user will still be authenticated because of the forms authentication cookie.

Comment: Another thing to consider - as far as I've experienced, ASP.NET session access will block, so that if you have a page issuing multiple AJAX requests to a server, and each of the requests try to read the session to get the authentication information, the requests will be processed serially, not in parallel. In other words, there's no way in ASP to say "I'm only reading the session here not writing to it". (That I know of).

Comment: @Mikeb, excellent remark. Thanks for pointing this out. I will update my answer to include this valuable information.